# Selenium code freezes after opening second window

Tags: selenium, popup, wait, popupwindow, freeze

Following code hangs for about 12 minutes after clicking on "Print Change" 
    button and then throws error that element not visible at line:
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print 
    Change')]")).click();

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\exe\\chromedriver.exe");      
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(prop.getProperty("https://genpact-qa-smartit.onbmc.com"));          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='okta-signin- 
username']")).sendKeys(userid);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='okta-signin- 
password']")).sendKeys(pwd);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='okta-signin-submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='header-search_button']")).click();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='globalSearchBox']")). 
sendKeys("CRQ000000029504");

Robot robot=new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='View Full Change']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Print']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print 
Change')]")).click();
System.out.println("Clicked on Print Change button");
```

I am using OS: Windows 10; Browser: Chrome 77.0.3865.90; Selenium: 3.141.59

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Surender

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376666/selenium-script-hangs-when-popup-window-is-opened-and-runs-normally-after-10-min

Answer (score 0):

First of all for your safety please edit your post removing your username and password that are in your code (and afterwards change them).

As far as your problem is concerned there is a high possibility that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print 
Change')]")).click();
```

there are more than one elements with the given xpath so the one you want might not be visible.
Therefore you should either be more specific with the:

```
[contains(text(),' ... ']
```

or try using the [css selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors).

Anyway look up the [docs for locating elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and if you still don't find a solution I will be happy to help you again.

Edit: In order to help you I logged in and your solution probably is to replace

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print 
Change')]")).click();
```

with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button[1])]")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print 
Change')]")).click();   works perfectly which opens up a new window. The issue is that after opening second window, System.out.println("Clicked on Print Change button"); does not work at all. selenium script freeezes.

Answer (score 0):

You specified an implicit wait of 120 seconds , so the code will wait for 120 seconds before throwing in to an exception.

in this case i think the xpath is wrong that's why its waiting for long time (may be there is some extra space in between the text print change). Use any xpath identification tool to check whether the xpath is correct or not

i hope the following code may work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print')]")).click();
```

Comment: xpathis correct. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print')]")).click(); will not work as button text is "Print Change". Also, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Print Change')]")).click(); works perfectly. The Issue is that System.out.println("Clicked on Print Change button"); does not work.

Comment: we are using contains text keyword .  When we use contains keyword, it doesn;t require mentioning of complete text (don't know why it didn't worked in this case). Just for a clarification,did you able to see **Clicked on Print Change button** on your console?

Comment: And if there is a second window, you may need to switch the control in to that particular window in order to do operations. let me know if there is any